# How to modify this formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have few Excel Sheets in workbook and i Need to use this formula for my results :

`=AVERAGEIFS(Motor!E:F;Motor!A:A;">="&DATE(2014;1;1);Motor!A:A;"<="&DATE(2014;12;31))`

So the formula above is working for range **E:E** but it doesnt work for range **E:F**

this formula works if instead direct date in the formula i put the range column and the Dates are inside, but i am trying to minimize the Input data fileds in my worksheet. 
So for example if i have:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Motor!E:E;Motor!A:A;Final_Data!F6;Motor!A:A;Final_Data!E6)
```

in the **F6** I have a date *>=01.01.2014* and in the **E6** a have the date *<=31.12.2014* then it works.

This is my sheet that ÷ am working on ّ[image: main sheet] and I Need the average
values from this sheet :

[image: Second sheet]

it should look something like this :

[image: Results]

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Why you have removed `">="&` and `"<="&`? without it you check for equality...  `=AVERAGEIFS(Motor!E:E;Motor!A:A;">="&Final_Data!F6;Motor!A:A;"<="&Final_Data!E6)`.

Comment: @Akina i havent removed them, is the first formula up the one that i am trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work with date format correctly. That means, date is actually number with starting position of 1.1.1900 with value "1". So if you insert "1" in any cell and change a format of the cell to "Date", you will see 1.1.1900. The best way for you is to use a formula with function date instead of the plan date in conditions.

So the formula would be

```
=AVERAGE(AVERAGEIFS(Motor!E:E;Motor!A:A;">="&DATE(2014;01;01);Motor!A:A;"<="&DATE(2014;12;31));AVERAGEIFS(Motor!F:F;Motor!A:A;">="&DATE(2014;01;01);Motor!A:A;"<="&DATE(2014;12;31)))
```

But there is still missing something behind the "Final_Data!" because this define only some sheet but not a cell you want to evaluate.

Comment: Thank you for Response, i tried as you said but it wont work ``=AVERAGEIFS(Motor!E:E;Motor!A:A;Final_Data!'DATE(>=2014;>=01;>=01);Motor!A:A;Final_Data!'DATE(<=2014;<=12;<=31)`` it gives me error right at the _Final_data!'DATE_

Comment: I tried your Version as well and it gives me the same error.

Comment: Don't use operators in Date formula and try to delete "Final_Data!'". Just use Date as the condition.   =AVERAGEIFS(Motor!E:E;Motor!A:A;>=DATE(2014;1;1);Motor!A:A;<=DATE(2014;12;2014))

Comment: It doesnt work , i tried like this : ``=AVERAGEIFS(Motor!E:E;Motor!A:A;">=DATE(2014;01;01)";Motor!A:A;"<=DATE(2014;12;31)")`` but wont give me the results just **#Value**

Comment: @Eidrizi Try to replace `">=DATE(2014;01;01)"` with `">="&DATE(2014;01;01)`.

Comment: @Akina i tried ``=AVERAGEIFS(Motor!$E$9:$F$32;Motor!A:A;">=&DATE(2014;01;01)";Motor!A:A;"<=&DATE(2014;12;31)")`` to be more specific on the range just to check if the values in the range are the reason behind it but again it doesnt work  and gives me this **#Value!**.

Comment: @Eidrizi Look CAREFULLY where doublequotes are placed!!!

Comment: =AVERAGEIFS(Motor!$E$9:$F$32;Motor!A:A;">="&DATE(2014;01;01);Motor!A:A;"<="&DATE(2014;12;31))

Comment: Perhaps you should [edit] the correct formula into your actual response instead of leaving pieces of it in the Comment section.

Comment: @Jeeped that is true. Thank you. I wrote all the comments on the way to work in a tram from mobile phone without Excel... Uncomfortable...

Comment: @Akina i tried also but it wont work, Japped i edited , Muji thank you for your help.

Comment: @Eidrizi I'd recommend you to publist some small sample file or insert some sample data (safe for copy-paste into Excel) into the question text with desured result on that data.

Comment: @Eidrizi, I found in the first formula you shared another mistake. You count from a range of E:F. In the second formula you count from a range E:E. So, the final working formula should be ```=AVERAGEIFS(Motor!E:E;Motor!A:A;">="&DATE(2014;01;01);Motor!A:A;"<="&DATE(2014;12;31))``` I updated also the main comment.

Comment: @Muji Thanks for updating the comment,, the formula works for E:E when i pres **CTRL+SHIFT** but it wont work with the range E:F

Comment: @Eidrizi, try this: ```=AVERAGE(AVERAGEIFS(Motor!E:E;Motor!A:A;">="&DATE(2014;01;01);Motor!A:A;"<="&DATE(2014;12;31));AVERAGEIFS(Motor!F:F;Motor!A:A;">="&DATE(2014;01;01);Motor!A:A;"<="&DATE(2014;12;31)))``` I updated also the main comment. Best regards, Lukas

Comment: @Muji thanks Lukas, i treid different ways , i decided to put values only in E:E so i would have to do so many formulas. But thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Eidrizi, but the flaw is much more fatal than suggested so far. (That fatal flaw is what underlies what Muji mentions in the comments.)

The function `AVERAGEIFS()` requires the criteria ranges to physically match in shape and size the "sum_range" which is the "average_range".

You wish to set it up so the sum_range (your range to average) is two columns wide while both of your criteria ranges are a single column wide.

The second formula does not work because you fiddled how the dates were presented. It works because you shifted to a single column for the range to average which matches the single column criteria ranges in the formula.

I would offer concrete solutions to the issue, as it CAN be fixed either by reorganizing a little or by turning the two columns into a single column either physically (helper column, actually just combine the column contents, etc.) or virtually (place a conatenation or joining of the content in the formula instead of the cell references (though that is not working out for me for some reason so...)) so that it matches the criteria range shape and size. But... it is entirely unclear to me just what is going on here as the ranges shown kind of seem opposite to what they should be.

Of course, a third way would be to use different functions altogether. So it seems perfectly fixable. But if flat cannot work as proposed. This dichotomy in how -IF/-IFS functions work in the use and form of their criteria plagues just about every pairing Excel has (count**IF**/count**IFS** is what I mean by **-IF/-IFS** pairings).